# Ruby on Rails save multiple sub records from a list in a text area

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, textarea

I have scoured stack overflow for and answer to my problem but can't find one.  So I was hoping that someone else out there has tried what I want to do before.

I have a question model, which has many options.  What I want to do is allow the user to copy a list of options into a textarea as a return/new line separated list.

i.e. a list of locations

> London 
>   Paris 
>   New York 
>   Singapore 
>   Sydney

And then from the questions controller I want to get each of these items insert them in the options model.

What I can't work out is how I access the textarea element from the controller as there is no object name associated with it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about it is associate the textarea element with your 'options' attribute, and then write a function in your model to split it into an array.

For example, in your view:

```
<%= form_for @question do |f| %>
...
<%= f.text_field :options %>
```

Then in your controller:

```
def create
  @question = Question.new(params[:question])

  ...
  @question.split_options

  ...
end
```

In the model, the `split_options` method could use Ruby's string split functions to return an array, which then gets saved.

Comment: Thanks Jonny, this is what I was thinking but I can't find examples of how to do this and can't make it work myself.  Do you have any example code for this?